# Iterate over array of hash

Tags: ruby

I have a array of hash something like

```
[{a1: 'a', b1: 'b'},{a1: 'c', b1: 'b'},{a1: 's', b1: 'cq'}]
```

I want to sort the array in the ascending value of b1 and return an array. Sorry if its easy but got confuse with the logic.

Comment: This is a pure-Ruby question, so you should remove the Rails tags (even though it's been marked as a duplicate). When you give an example, please assign a variable to each input (e.g., `arr = [{a1:....]`) so that readers can refer to those variables in comments and answers without having to define them. Also, show your desired output for the example's input data.

Answer (score 0):

Following will return you an array sorted based on b1

```
array_of_hashes.sort_by { |hsh| hsh[:b1] }
```

Comment: no, it won't do that.

Comment: Why? Whats the issue in this?

Comment: yeah, the second version will work. but not the first one.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: yea, my bad, removing the firrst one

Comment: I have an hash say
     
test =  [{:a1=>"a", :b1=>"q"}, {:a1=>"c", :b1=>"z"}, {:a1=>"a", :b1=>"zcq"}]

Need to find out count of key with "a"(:a1=>"a") in a hash. How to find the count of the selected `key`.